# php Fetch(), SQL Join, in a while()

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to display a clients projects. I would like to display the client information once and the projects multiple times

```
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT client.client_id, client.firstname, client.lastname, project.project_title
                            FROM client
                            INNER JOIN project ON client.client_id = project.client_id
                            WHERE client.client_id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $userid);

    $userid = $_GET['clientid'];
    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->bind_result($clientid, $firstname, $lastname, $project);

    while($stmt->fetch()){
        echo $clientid;
        echo $project;
    }
```

The problem I have is the `$clientid` will not work anywhere out side of the `$stmt->fetch()`, just as I can not use the `$stmt->fetch()` out side the while to get the `$clientid` and use the `$stmt->fetch()` again for the while loop.

Is there away to call and Display the Client information once, and the project information multiple times?

Comment: Yes, you would package everything in a function and then return an associative array from the function. You can then use that array as much as you need to, loop through it, pick from it, etc.

Comment: Sorry for silly question (its been a long day). How would I go about doing it?

Comment: Before making someone go through writing code for you, I would advise taking a stab at it first.

Comment: I have been since 6:00pm (currently 11:42pm).... coming here was my last option after countless tutorials, YouTube videos, reading forums and messing about with the code my self. 

I dont expect other people to write my code out for me, more so give me help with logic and throw a php function I can use which I can research or something.

Comment: If you need further advice, we need to see more of what your code is doing. Don't mean to be a jerk, but we can't do the work for you.

Comment: of course not, as I don't expect anyone too.... Like I said, just someone to help with Logic or a php function I could use. Copying and Pasting someone else code takes away the fun. 

This is basically the code being executed at the moment, no other besides the connection string.

(Since this post I have tried storing two bind_results, apparently we can do that nor can you call fetch twice)

Comment: Did the plan I suggested not work?

Answer (score 0):

Just an example how you can ,"save" the data. I think you must read about how scopes works in php.

```
$clients = array();
$projects = array();
$some_id = null;
while($stmt->fetch()){
  $clients[] = $clientid;
  $projects[] = $project;
  $some_id = $clientid;
}
```